# Scrape with scrapy using saved html pages

Tags: html, web-scraping, scrapy, local

I'm looking to find a way to use scrapy with html pages that I saved on my computer. As far as I am, I got an error :

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'file:///home/stage/Guillaume/scraper_test/mypage/details.html'
```

SPIDER_START_URLS = ["file:///home/stage/Guillaume/scraper_test/mypage/details.html"]

Comment: 1. Unless I'm being very mistaken, Scrapy has been supporting the `file:` scheme for quite long.
2. According to the log you shared, it looks like something generated by `requests` the famous HTTP client library, not Scrapy.

Comment: For now i really don't know and as I'm new to scrappy i will not loose any time and use a static server

Comment: Sorry for not having made myself clear. I thought that you probably need to provide further information (more lines of log? some related code? etc.) before others could try digging further and helping.

Comment: all log : Unhandled error in Deferred:

2018-11-09 13:05:25 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stage/miniconda3/envs/scrapy_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/stage/miniconda3/envs/scrapy_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 82, in crawl
    yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'file:///home/stage/Guillaume/scraper_test/mypage/details.html'

Answer (score 1):

I have had great success with using [`request_fingerprint`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.5.1/scrapy/utils/request.py#L19) to inject existing HTML files into [`HTTPCACHE_DIR`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.5.1/scrapy/extensions/httpcache.py#L275) (which is almost always `.scrapy/httpcache/${spider_name}`). Then, turning on the aforementioned [http cache middleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.5/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache) which defaults to the file based cache storage, and the "Dummy Policy" which considers the on-disk file authoritative and won't make a network request if it finds the URL in the cache.

I would expect the script would something like (this is just the general idea, and not guaranteed to even run):

```
import sys
from scrapy.extensions.httpcache import FilesystemCacheStorage
from scrapy.http import Request, HtmlResponse
from scrapy.settings import Settings

# this value is the actual URL from which the on-disk file was saved
# not the "file://" version
url = sys.argv[1]
html_filename = sys.argv[2]
with open(html_filename) as fh:
    html_bytes = fh.read()
req = Request(url=url)
resp = HtmlResponse(url=req.url, body=html_bytes, encoding='utf-8', request=req)
settings = Settings()
cache = FilesystemCacheStorage(settings)
spider = None  # fill in your Spider class here
cache.store_response(spider, req, resp)
```